# Script out insert script with dependency in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

we want Script out insert script with dependency in multiple table.

For example – TABLEA is Master table- here I want to insert 1 record from old version of table script out earlier (SSMS-TASK-Generate script), but due to dependency in another table it will not work.

Regards,
Manish

Answer (score 0):

If you have the real foreign key between your tables, **SMSS Generate Scripts Task** takes care of the dependencies and the master table insert script will be generated before the detail tables.